# mailchimp unsubscribe form after registration - on my website

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, mailchimp, newsletter

I want to use mail chimp for the newsletter on my web form.
When the user subscribes, I want to show on the page the unsubscribe form.
But, how can I check if the user has already subscribed ? 
Is there a way to check it from the mail chimp ?

I just want to find the logic to write my code.

Comment: @GeoffJames brilliant. Dora, Welcome to SO! Please post code that you've already tried, StackOverflow is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Mailchimp API guide](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/overview/). There is:

```
/lists/{list_id}/members/{subscriber_hash}
```

which returns the user. If no user is returned, he is not in the list; if a user is returned, check his status (could be subscribed, unsubscribed, cleaned, pending).

The {list_id} if of course the list of the list you want to search; the {subscriber_hash} is the MD5 hash of the email address you want to find.